# View inside property observer throwing "Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file"

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to update the view based on the change in items variable but cartView is nil in didSet

```swift
@IBOutlet weak var cartView: UIView!

var items = 0 {
    didSet{
        if items > 0 {
            cartView.isHidden = false
        } else {
            cartView.isHidden = true
        }
    }
    willSet{}
}
```

Updating this var from tableviewcell like this --
'''
class ItemListingItemsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

```
@IBOutlet weak var itemTypeImage: UIImageView!


@IBOutlet weak var itemName: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var itemPrice: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var itemAdd: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var itemMinus: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var itemPlus: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var buttonsview: UIView!


**var itemVC = ItemListingViewController()**



@IBAction func addItemInitial(_ sender: Any) {
    itemAdd.isEnabled = false
    itemAdd.setTitle("1", for: .normal)
    itemAdd.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    itemMinus.isHidden = false
    itemPlus.isHidden = false

    itemVC.items = itemVC.items + 1


}'''
```

Comment: You are probably setting the `items` from another controller. You should make sure `cartView` is initialized (and loaded) before calling it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Comment: Yes, I am setting items from the tableviewcell class and viewDidLoad is being called before this property observer

Comment: Basically you need to check whether your `cartView` is not `nil` in the begging of `didSet`, e.g. `guard cartView != nil else { return }`

Comment: Or just `cartView?.isHidden = items <= 0`.

Comment: @Dennis Pashkov, I tried this but it's always returning nil

Comment: @user28434 Thank you, that seems efficient but my problem is with the cartView always returning nil. Can you suggest any way to update this view?

Comment: Have you linked your `@IBOutlet` in `Storyboard`/`Xib`?

Comment: Yes, I linked it

Comment: @keerthi I've posted an answer that might fix your problem

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are modifying `count` before the outlet `cartView` is set. I've modified your code by checking if `cartView` is `nil` + added an observer to the cartView itself, so once the outlet is assigned, your `cartView` immediately updates its state based on the `count` property value.

Please also make sure that `cartView` outlet is connected in your xib/storyboard.

```
@IBOutlet private weak var cartView: UIView! {
    didSet {
        updateCartViewVisibility()
    }
}

var items = 0 {
    didSet{
        updateCartViewVisibility()
    }
}

private func updateCartViewVisibility() {
    guard cartView != nil else { return }
    cartView.isHidden = items == .zero
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but even here all the views are nil. I can't understand what I am doing wrong

Comment: @keerthi then your Outlet is not set. Check storyboard/xib

Comment: It is connected to the storyboard

Comment: I understood my mistake, In my tableViewCell I am referencing the view controller like  var itemVC = ItemListingViewController() which is the reason why the views are not initialised.  Can you suggest some other way to update variable in view controller from tableviewcell?

Comment: @keerthi difficult to say anything without the code

Comment: Oh that's okay, thanks for the help! It is fixed now. I shifted the entire logic to view controller.